# Matrix, linearly independent real eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

The maximum value of $a$ such that the matrix
$$
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
–3    &  0 &  –2\\
   1  & –1    &  0\\
   0   &   a  & –2\\
\end{array}
\right]
$$
has three linearly independent real eigen vectors is :

1. $\frac{2}{3\sqrt3}$
2. $\frac{1}{3\sqrt3}$
3. $\frac{1+2\sqrt3}{3\sqrt3}$
4. $\frac{1+\sqrt 3}{3\sqrt3}$

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem? What have you tried?

Comment: [How To Ask A Homework Question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question).

Comment: I thought if the given matrix has three distinct real eigen values then the corresponding eigen vectors will be linearly independent. So I formed the characteristic equation of the given matrix λ³ + 6λ² + 11λ + 6 + 2a = 0. Now how to proceed further to find the conditions for distinct roots for this characteristic equation.

Answer (score 2):

One approach is as follows.  The characteristic polynomial is given by
$$
p(\lambda) = \lambda^3 + 6 \lambda^2 + 11\lambda + (2a + 6).
$$
The discriminant of this polynomial is given by $\Delta = 4 - 108a^2$. The matrix will fail to be diagonalizable over $\Bbb R$ whenever the polynomial fails to have $3$ real roots (either distinct or repeated), which occurs if and only if the discriminant is negative.

The greatest value of $a$ for which this occurs is the positive root to $\Delta = 0$.

Comment: Answer given is :
a = 1 / 3√3

Solution is NOT given.

Comment: $a = \frac 1{3 \sqrt{3}}$ is choice 2 from the answers you've shown, I don't understand the problem